# Select ALL fields that contains only UPPERCASE letters

Tags: mysql

How do you select a field that contains only uppercase character in mysql or a field that doesn't contain any lower case character?

Comment: Are the fields allowed to contain non-letters?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may want to use a case sensitive [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html). I believe the default is case insensitive. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id int,
   name varchar(50)
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'SomeThing');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'something');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'SOMETHING');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (4, 'SOME4THING');
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
|    3 | SOMETHING |
+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't want to use a case sensitive collation for the whole table, you can also use the [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html) clause as [@kchau suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22371/kchau).

Let's try with a table using a case insensitive collation:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id int,
   name varchar(50)
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'SomeThing');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'something');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'SOMETHING');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (4, 'SOME4THING');
```

This won't work very well:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | SomeThing |
|    2 | something |
|    3 | SOMETHING |
+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But we can use the `COLLATE` clause to collate the name field to a case sensitive collation:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (name COLLATE latin1_general_cs) REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
|    3 | SOMETHING |
+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: another way is to use BINARY compare BINARY city_name = BINARY upper(city_name)

Comment: @AivanMonceller BINARY is the better answer in fact :)

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me. It found all user emails with uppercase character:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]';
```

Comment: "REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings." -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (columnname COLLATE latin1_bin )=UPPER(depart);
```

Comment: That will also select fields that contain numbers and other characters. I don't think the OP wants that.

Answer (score 3):

By using `REGEXP` : http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

Use `[:upper:]` for uppercase letters.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^[[:upper:]+]$'
```

Comment: using [:upper:] would also select 'Example' .. [^a-z] doesn't seem to work fine

Answer (score 2):

Found this in the comments - it deserves a post of its own:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE BINARY mycolumn = BINARY UPPER(mycolumn);
```

The problem with `WHERE UPPER(mycolumn) = mycolumn` is the collation, and it depends on your table what you can use there.

Answer (score 1):

Basic [eg](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP '[A-Z]';
```

Comment: not working thanks SELECT 'as' REGEXP '[A-Z]' returns 1 SELECT 'AS' REGEXP '[A-Z]' returns 1

Comment: Can your field contain other characters, such as spaces, etc? If so, you would want to include those in the regular expression pattern as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM <mytable> WHERE UPPER(<columnname>) = <columnname>
```

Comment: That will not work with a case insensitive collation. In addition, that will also select fields that contain numbers and other characters. I don't think the OP wants that.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, I agree this does not handle special characters. But the question is not clear about he wants or does not want to retain special characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]+$'
```