# mysql queryto list only uppercase row from database

Tags: mysql

i have one table which consists of 10 columns out of which one column is username . the column username stores the name of student which may be in uppercase and lowercase .
i want to segregate the uppercase and lowercase students.if the username consists of any uppercase it will list the row.
i am interested in doing query for column username.in other column also uppercase letters are there but i want to list based on username column only. i have tried several query but no one is working.please advice

i want to list rows with any upperletter in column username.
i have tried these codes

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE LOWER(username) LIKE '%q'
```

did not worked

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%q')
```

did not worked

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where username COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = '%q'
```

did not worked

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username REGEXP '[A-Z]';
```

did not worked

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username REGEXP '^[[:upper:]+]$'
```

did not worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *          
FROM accounts          
WHERE CAST(username AS BINARY) RLIKE '[A-Z]';
```

Comment: you rocks exactly what i was searching. what does this cast do please explain

Comment: it does a binary regex match for the expression [A-Z] (looks for uppercase letters) and then returns anything that matches. Please vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
   id int,
   username varchar(50)
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

SELECT* FROM accounts WHERE username REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
```

Make sure you use **COLLATE latin1_general_ci**

Answer (score 0):

You were on track with the collation, but you need to have **a table** that is collated, not just the query. What you could do is create a new table, then insert your current rows into the new collated table, then try the REGEX or the rest of the methods.

[Select ALL fields that contains only UPPERCASE letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836825/select-all-fields-that-contains-only-uppercase-letters)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work fine

select *   from TABLE where CAST( COL_NAME AS BINARY) = upper(COL_NAME);

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to make sure the field you are searching on have a case-specific collation like latin1_general_cs (if you are using latin character set).  Then you can just search for uppercase or lower case, whichever is you are looking for (i.e. WHERE username LIKE '%q%' or WHERE username LIKE '%Q%'

Answer (score -1):

Mysql is case insensitive for strings, so it will be more complecated than a single seletect statement.  If you want to do this comparison often, convert the type of the username column to one of the binary types listed below:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

If you don't want to do this often, consider saving off the results of the current table to a temp table, altering that table with a case sensitive string type, and then using your regex.