# Return all records with whole word in UPPERCASE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, uppercase

Could someone tell me how to return all records that have whole words in uppercase?  If at all possible.

I currently have a database that has a list of drugs.  Historically the drug names have been entered as DRUGNAME 10mg Tablets.  We are now undertaking an exercise to change them all to Drugname 10mg Tablets.

Of course i cannot run a task to change all upper to lower because i would like the first letter to be upper.  And when i run:

```
select drugname from medication where upper(drugname) = drugname
```

I get all results with any uppercase letters returned, so also useless to me.

How can i target the records with whole words in uppercase please?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you tried using regex? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452572/mysql-regex-in-the-where-clause

Comment: Please have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836825/select-all-fields-that-contains-only-uppercase-letters

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT drugname FROM medication WHERE drugname regex '\b[[:upper:]]+\b'
```

[You can read more about regex here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use case sensitive collation to do this (generally use collation ending with _cs):

```
select drugname from medication where drugname COLLATE latin1_general_cs rlike '^[[:upper:]]+'
```

Regexp will return all strings with first word uppercase.